# Post XML List to Elasticsearch with requests?

Tags: python, xml, elasticsearch, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to post an XML List to Elasticsearch using the requests module? 
The List looks like this:

```
[{'author': 'author name 1',
  'content': 'content',
  'title': 'title 1'},

 {'author': 'author name 2',
  'content': 'content',
  'title': 'title 2'},

 {'author': 'author name 3',
  'content': 'content',
  'title': 'title 3'}]
```

I have a corpus with XML files that I parsed with etree:

```
for file in corpus:
    tree = etree.parse(file)
    doc = {
    "author": tree.xpath('//tei:author/text()', namespaces=ns)[0],
    "title": tree.xpath('//tei:title/text()', namespaces=ns)[0],
    "content": "".join(tree.xpath('//tei:text/text()', namespaces=ns))
    }
    xmlList.append(doc)
```

I am now trying to post this to Elasticsearch using requests:

```
response = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/test/test',
             json=xmlList)
```

but this gives me a bad request (400).

Comment: This is a (almost) JSON string, not XML. Also, this question is pretty vague. If you can POST to it, you most certainly can do it with requests. You need to provide some more details.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using requests. There is a python Elasticsearch library you could be using

Comment: You should have a look at the official Python elasticsearch module and the [bulk helpers](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk), it will be easier to use than trying to format bulk queries using the `requests` module.